# How to see reason for close votes in advance?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, user-interface, close-reasons

How the user can see the reason to close his/her question before it has enough votes to be closed? All I see is `close(2/3/4)`, but if I would know the reason in advance I could improve a question.

Comment: You could improve the questions by reading help on [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Did you try clicking on `close(2/3/4)`?

Comment: @Yannis, no. Don't people suppose to click on "close" when they want to to close the topic?

Comment: Yes, but it's also the way to see how others have voted. Clicking the link will bring up the close dialog and show you the pending close reasons (and then you can simply close the dialog without voting to close).

Comment: @Yannis, this would be an answer to my question. Do you want to post it (so I can accept it and other people can see it), or I do it?

Comment: @klm123 I was about to, when I noticed the duplicate. Grace's answer there also answers your question (and mentions the 250 rep requirement, that I had no idea about), so I just voted to close. Unfortunately you don't have 250 rep on MSO and can't test the feature on this question.